# SharePoint Timer Service

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, service

I am getting following error when change "SharePoint Timer Service" in service account in WFE server.

> The account name is invalid or does not exist, or the password is invalid for the account name specified

Comment: why you are not changing the timer service account from the Services? how many server in the farm

Comment: Its 3 tier farm and i trying to change the service account in services.msc

Answer (score 0):

You should not do it via services console. SharePoint Timer Service should run under the farm admin account. If you want to update the password for it then

- Go to Central admin > Security > Configure Managed Accounts
- On this page click on the account and update the password.

If you want to change the farm admin account then follow the below stsadm command.

```
stsadm.exe -o updatefarmcredentials
 -userlogin DOMAIN\username -password password
```

http://www.codemag.com/Article/1409021

Or try to login with the farm admin account then try to change the Sharepoint timer service under your farm admin account. as it is only running under local account on one server out of 3.

Comment: I used your stsadm command.The command ran quite good.But still my "SharePoint Timer Service" running with local service account in my WFE server

Comment: it should not be local admin, anybody change? under which account central admin app pool is running?

Comment: is it ruuning under local account onall servers?

Comment: No..In my apps server its running with "spfarm" account.But,In my WFE its running with local system account

Comment: do you have the User name and password for the SPfarm?

Comment: Yes..i do have username and password for spfarm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45811/discussion-between-user52682-and-waqas-sarwar-mcse).